# Very very slow Entity Framework Execution Of Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I'm using 6.1.1 of entity framework against SQL Server 2012.

I've attached the query in question to this issue.

When run against our DB directly (i.e. from the SQL Generated) this query responds in < 15ms.

However, when processed in Entity Framework it's ~650 ms to materialization to the projection (thus no tracking causing issues)

Further, when using Web API and Odata to do a top 100 it's even slower. (i.e. if I do a .ToArray() on the results in the endpoint in Web API controller first, it's faster than the filtered top 100 query through odata.

Worse, the inlinecount query by oData which causes a groupby on a count to be generated by Entity Framework, which is odd, takes < 10ms to process on the server, but takes the same length of time for Entity Framework to process as the full select thus doubling the service time.

I can understand some overhead, but we're talking about 100 records into a projection, it shouldn't take more than half a second to process this.

Also, I would have expected that, given the complexity of the where clause (generated using predicates) that the second time this was hit, that it would be drastically faster because of dynamic caching in EF 5+ but it doesn't make any difference at all.

I can provide you with the DTO that it's projecting into if it matters but it's just strings and datetimeoffsets straight up with no computation or anything.

Also note that all tests were done in release mode, not debug mode. And timers were used to isolate the 2 separate queries in a custom formatter and time how long it took entity framework to service them.

I went down to the DB level and created a DB reader and looped through the results and manually created the DTOs to work with (all of them, not the filtered ones) using the exact same query generated, just putting in different values for the params and it completed in < 30 ms for reference.

If you'd like me to somehow provide you with the built up predicate that generated this, please let me know and give me instructions and I'll be happy to do so.

Here's the resulting query (which again ,runs in 30 ms, but Entity Framework takes 2.5 seconds to produce the result and get it out the door with WebAPI:

```
SELECT TOP (@p__linq__15) 
[Project45].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Project45].[C6] AS [C1], 
[Project45].[C7] AS [C2], 
[Project45].[C1] AS [C3], 
[Project45].[C8] AS [C4], 
[Project45].[Priority] AS [Priority], 
[Project45].[C9] AS [C5], 
[Project45].[Name1] AS [Name], 
[Project45].[C10] AS [C6], 
[Project45].[Name2] AS [Name1], 
[Project45].[C11] AS [C7], 
[Project45].[C12] AS [C8], 
[Project45].[C4] AS [C9], 
[Project45].[C13] AS [C10], 
[Project45].[C5] AS [C11], 
[Project45].[C14] AS [C12], 
[Project45].[C3] AS [C13], 
[Project45].[C15] AS [C14], 
[Project45].[C2] AS [C15], 
[Project45].[C16] AS [C16], 
[Project45].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
[Project45].[C17] AS [C17], 
[Project45].[Name] AS [Name2], 
[Project45].[C18] AS [C18], 
[Project45].[ID] AS [ID]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[ID1] AS [ID], 
    [Filter1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
    [Filter1].[Name1] AS [Name], 
    [Filter1].[Priority] AS [Priority], 
    [Filter1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Filter1].[Name2] AS [Name1], 
    [Filter1].[Name3] AS [Name2], 
     CAST( [Filter1].[DueDate] AS datetimeoffset) AS [C1], 
     CAST( CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[CancelledOn] IS NULL) THEN CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[RejectedOn1] IS NULL) THEN CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[SubmittedOn] IS NULL) THEN [Filter1].[CreatedOn] ELSE [Filter1].[SubmittedOn] END ELSE [Filter1].[RejectedOn1] END ELSE [Filter1].[CancelledOn] END AS datetimeoffset) AS [C2], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[CancelledByID] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Filter1].[UserName1] WHEN ([Filter1].[RejectedByID1] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Filter1].[UserName2] WHEN ([Filter1].[SubmittedByID] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Filter1].[UserName3] ELSE [Filter1].[UserName4] END AS [C3], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[FirstName1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Filter1].[FirstName2] END + N' ' + CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[LastName1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Filter1].[LastName2] END AS [C4], 
     CAST( [Filter1].[SubmittedOn] AS datetimeoffset) AS [C5], 
    N'c4eabbaf-7433-430d-bdd7-2f9180bce7cc' AS [C6], 
    N'DueDate' AS [C7], 
    N'Priority' AS [C8], 
    N'Project' AS [C9], 
    N'RequestType' AS [C10], 
    N'Status' AS [C11], 
    N'SubmittedByName' AS [C12], 
    N'SubmittedOn' AS [C13], 
    N'MajorEventBy' AS [C14], 
    N'MajorEventDate' AS [C15], 
    N'Identifier' AS [C16], 
    N'Name' AS [C17], 
    N'ID' AS [C18]
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID1], [Extent1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent1].[Priority] AS [Priority], [Extent1].[DueDate] AS [DueDate], [Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], [Extent1].[CreatedByID] AS [CreatedByID], [Extent1].[SubmittedOn] AS [SubmittedOn], [Extent1].[SubmittedByID] AS [SubmittedByID], [Extent1].[RejectedOn] AS [RejectedOn1], [Extent1].[RejectedByID] AS [RejectedByID1], [Extent1].[CancelledOn] AS [CancelledOn], [Extent1].[CancelledByID] AS [CancelledByID], [Extent1].[Private] AS [Private], [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], [Extent2].[UserName] AS [UserName1], [Extent3].[UserName] AS [UserName2], [Extent4].[UserName] AS [UserName3], [Extent5].[UserName] AS [UserName4], [Extent6].[Name] AS [Name2], [Extent7].[Name] AS [Name3], [Extent8].[FirstName] AS [FirstName1], [Extent9].[FirstName] AS [FirstName2], [Extent10].[LastName] AS [LastName1], [Extent11].[LastName] AS [LastName2]
        FROM           [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CancelledByID] = [Extent2].[ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[RejectedByID] = [Extent3].[ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[SubmittedByID] = [Extent4].[ID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[CreatedByID] = [Extent5].[ID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Projects] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[ProjectID] = [Extent6].[ID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[RequestTypes] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent1].[RequestTypeID] = [Extent7].[ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent1].[SubmittedByID] = [Extent8].[ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent1].[SubmittedByID] = [Extent9].[ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent1].[SubmittedByID] = [Extent10].[ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent1].[SubmittedByID] = [Extent11].[ID]
        WHERE [Extent1].[isDeleted] <> cast(1 as bit)
    )  AS [Filter1]
    WHERE (( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclDataMarts] AS [Extent12]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent13]
            WHERE ([Extent12].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent13].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent13].[UserID] = @p__linq__0)
        )) AND ([Extent12].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5d6dd388-7842-40a1-a27a-b9782a445e20' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a58791b5-e8af-48d0-b9cd-ed0b54e564e6' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0cabf382-93d3-4dac-aa80-2de500a5f945' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[RequestDataMarts] AS [Extent14]
            WHERE ([Extent12].[DataMartID] = [Extent14].[DataMartID]) AND ([Extent14].[RequestID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        ))
    )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclProjects] AS [Extent15]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent16]
            WHERE ([Extent15].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent16].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent16].[UserID] = @p__linq__1)
        )) AND ([Extent15].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5d6dd388-7842-40a1-a27a-b9782a445e20' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a58791b5-e8af-48d0-b9cd-ed0b54e564e6' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0cabf382-93d3-4dac-aa80-2de500a5f945' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0549f5c8-6c0e-4491-be90-ee0f29652422' as uniqueidentifier), cast('40db7de2-eefa-4d31-b400-7e72ab34de99' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent17]
            WHERE ([Extent15].[ProjectID] = [Extent17].[ProjectID]) AND ([Extent17].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        ))
    )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclProjectDataMarts] AS [Extent18]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent19]
            WHERE ([Extent18].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent19].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent19].[UserID] = @p__linq__2)
        )) AND ([Extent18].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5d6dd388-7842-40a1-a27a-b9782a445e20' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a58791b5-e8af-48d0-b9cd-ed0b54e564e6' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0cabf382-93d3-4dac-aa80-2de500a5f945' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[RequestDataMarts] AS [Extent20]
            WHERE ([Extent18].[DataMartID] = [Extent20].[DataMartID]) AND ([Extent20].[RequestID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent21]
            WHERE ([Extent18].[ProjectID] = [Extent21].[ProjectID]) AND ([Extent21].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        ))
    )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclGlobal] AS [Extent22]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent23]
            WHERE ([Extent22].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent23].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent23].[UserID] = @p__linq__3)
        )) AND ([Extent22].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5d6dd388-7842-40a1-a27a-b9782a445e20' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a58791b5-e8af-48d0-b9cd-ed0b54e564e6' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0cabf382-93d3-4dac-aa80-2de500a5f945' as uniqueidentifier), cast('5ccb0ec2-006d-4345-895e-5dd2c6c8c791' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0549f5c8-6c0e-4491-be90-ee0f29652422' as uniqueidentifier), cast('40db7de2-eefa-4d31-b400-7e72ab34de99' as uniqueidentifier)))
    )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclRequestSharedFolders] AS [Extent24]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent25]
            WHERE ([Extent24].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent25].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent25].[UserID] = @p__linq__4)
        )) AND ([Extent24].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5ccb0ec2-006d-4345-895e-5dd2c6c8c791' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[RequestSharedFolderRequests] AS [Extent26]
            WHERE ([Extent24].[RequestSharedFolderID] = [Extent26].[RequestSharedFolderID]) AND ([Extent26].[RequestID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        ))
    )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclOrganizations] AS [Extent27]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent28]
            WHERE ([Extent27].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent28].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent28].[UserID] = @p__linq__5)
        )) AND ([Extent27].[PermissionID] IN (cast('0549f5c8-6c0e-4491-be90-ee0f29652422' as uniqueidentifier), cast('40db7de2-eefa-4d31-b400-7e72ab34de99' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent29]
            WHERE ([Extent27].[OrganizationID] = [Extent29].[OrganizationID]) AND ([Extent29].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        ))
    )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclProjectOrganizations] AS [Extent30]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent31]
            WHERE ([Extent30].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent31].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent31].[UserID] = @p__linq__6)
        )) AND ([Extent30].[PermissionID] IN (cast('0549f5c8-6c0e-4491-be90-ee0f29652422' as uniqueidentifier), cast('40db7de2-eefa-4d31-b400-7e72ab34de99' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent32]
            WHERE ([Extent30].[ProjectID] = [Extent32].[ProjectID]) AND ([Extent32].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent33]
            WHERE ([Extent30].[OrganizationID] = [Extent33].[OrganizationID]) AND ([Extent33].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        ))
    ))) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclDataMarts] AS [Extent34]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent35]
            WHERE ([Extent34].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent35].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent35].[UserID] = @p__linq__7)
        )) AND ([Extent34].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5d6dd388-7842-40a1-a27a-b9782a445e20' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a58791b5-e8af-48d0-b9cd-ed0b54e564e6' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0cabf382-93d3-4dac-aa80-2de500a5f945' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[RequestDataMarts] AS [Extent36]
            WHERE ([Extent34].[DataMartID] = [Extent36].[DataMartID]) AND ([Extent36].[RequestID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ([Extent34].[Allowed] <> cast(1 as bit))
    )) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclProjects] AS [Extent37]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent38]
            WHERE ([Extent37].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent38].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent38].[UserID] = @p__linq__8)
        )) AND ([Extent37].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5d6dd388-7842-40a1-a27a-b9782a445e20' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a58791b5-e8af-48d0-b9cd-ed0b54e564e6' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0cabf382-93d3-4dac-aa80-2de500a5f945' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0549f5c8-6c0e-4491-be90-ee0f29652422' as uniqueidentifier), cast('40db7de2-eefa-4d31-b400-7e72ab34de99' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent39]
            WHERE ([Extent37].[ProjectID] = [Extent39].[ProjectID]) AND ([Extent39].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ([Extent37].[Allowed] <> cast(1 as bit))
    )) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclProjectDataMarts] AS [Extent40]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent41]
            WHERE ([Extent40].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent41].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent41].[UserID] = @p__linq__9)
        )) AND ([Extent40].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5d6dd388-7842-40a1-a27a-b9782a445e20' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a58791b5-e8af-48d0-b9cd-ed0b54e564e6' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0cabf382-93d3-4dac-aa80-2de500a5f945' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[RequestDataMarts] AS [Extent42]
            WHERE ([Extent40].[DataMartID] = [Extent42].[DataMartID]) AND ([Extent42].[RequestID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent43]
            WHERE ([Extent40].[ProjectID] = [Extent43].[ProjectID]) AND ([Extent43].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ([Extent40].[Allowed] <> cast(1 as bit))
    )) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclGlobal] AS [Extent44]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent45]
            WHERE ([Extent44].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent45].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent45].[UserID] = @p__linq__10)
        )) AND ([Extent44].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5d6dd388-7842-40a1-a27a-b9782a445e20' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a58791b5-e8af-48d0-b9cd-ed0b54e564e6' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0cabf382-93d3-4dac-aa80-2de500a5f945' as uniqueidentifier), cast('5ccb0ec2-006d-4345-895e-5dd2c6c8c791' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0549f5c8-6c0e-4491-be90-ee0f29652422' as uniqueidentifier), cast('40db7de2-eefa-4d31-b400-7e72ab34de99' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ([Extent44].[Allowed] <> cast(1 as bit))
    )) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclRequestSharedFolders] AS [Extent46]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent47]
            WHERE ([Extent46].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent47].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent47].[UserID] = @p__linq__11)
        )) AND ([Extent46].[PermissionID] IN (cast('5ccb0ec2-006d-4345-895e-5dd2c6c8c791' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[RequestSharedFolderRequests] AS [Extent48]
            WHERE ([Extent46].[RequestSharedFolderID] = [Extent48].[RequestSharedFolderID]) AND ([Extent48].[RequestID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ([Extent46].[Allowed] <> cast(1 as bit))
    )) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclOrganizations] AS [Extent49]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent50]
            WHERE ([Extent49].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent50].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent50].[UserID] = @p__linq__12)
        )) AND ([Extent49].[PermissionID] IN (cast('0549f5c8-6c0e-4491-be90-ee0f29652422' as uniqueidentifier), cast('40db7de2-eefa-4d31-b400-7e72ab34de99' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent51]
            WHERE ([Extent49].[OrganizationID] = [Extent51].[OrganizationID]) AND ([Extent51].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ([Extent49].[Allowed] <> cast(1 as bit))
    )) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AclProjectOrganizations] AS [Extent52]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupUsers] AS [Extent53]
            WHERE ([Extent52].[SecurityGroupID] = [Extent53].[SecurityGroupID]) AND ([Extent53].[UserID] = @p__linq__13)
        )) AND ([Extent52].[PermissionID] IN (cast('0549f5c8-6c0e-4491-be90-ee0f29652422' as uniqueidentifier), cast('40db7de2-eefa-4d31-b400-7e72ab34de99' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent54]
            WHERE ([Extent52].[ProjectID] = [Extent54].[ProjectID]) AND ([Extent54].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent55]
            WHERE ([Extent52].[OrganizationID] = [Extent55].[OrganizationID]) AND ([Extent55].[ID] = [Filter1].[ID1])
        )) AND ([Extent52].[Allowed] <> cast(1 as bit))
    )) AND (([Filter1].[Private] <> cast(1 as bit)) OR (([Filter1].[Private] = 1) AND ([Filter1].[CreatedByID] = @p__linq__14)))
)  AS [Project45]
ORDER BY [Project45].[Identifier] DESC, [Project45].[ID] ASC
```

Comment: Can you check what's EF generated SQL is?

Comment: Where is the query? Show your EF code.

Comment: Are you using IQueryable or IEnumerable?

Comment: To help see the sql that EF is executing, You can setup basic EF logging without recompiling. http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/09/ef-6-1-turning-on-logging-without-recompiling/

Comment: It generates an IQueryable building up a where clause using predicate builder in a loop based on some properties of the identity of the user. (A security function that knows how to secure an object based on meta-data)  Hence I can't show my EF code because it's just being built up.  But in short it builds 2 predicates: An "Any" that checks that they have at least one allow, and an "All" that ensures that there are no denied in the chain. It then Ands those and adds it to the where. I'll edit the original question with the generated SQL.

Comment: if your query is fixed you can try compile the query before execute to make faster execution (see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336024.aspx)

Comment: did you try to do a warm-up call to the DB? EF will take several seconds to make the first call to the DB because it is loading a bunch of stuff but after that any query is very fast.

Comment: Yes, this is after warm-up. Before warm-up it takes > 10 seconds)

Comment: abrfra: Pre-compiling is not applicable with code-first in V6.1 as it does it automatically. (and apparently isn't doing anything in this case because it doesn't get faster between runs) As far as I'm aware there is no way to force a compile in code-first in V6.1

Answer (score 1):

EF take a long time to convert LINQ to a SQL query.

**Your query is not automaticaly cached because it use an in-memory collection as parameter (the uuid collection).**

See MSDN page [Performance Considerations (Entity Framework)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc853327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A solution (not really ideal) is to serialize this parameter and use the `String.Contains` operator.